# Zend Framework multi-module-subdomain isolated bootstrapping using environment variables and a tweaked index.php

Tags: apache, zend-framework, module, subdomain, bootstrapping

I've been struggling to get to grips with implementing a multi-module ZF application. I've found a whole bunch of resources out there about multi-module applications, and the fact that in ZF < v2.0 the whole module thing is less than optimal. I've come to the conclusion that for the particular implementation we'll be using, all the existing methods I've read about have some kind of drawback that is a show-stopper for us, so I started thinking out of the box.

I've come up with a solution that works, and allows multi-module isolated bootstrapping, but I'd like to get some input from some ZF gurus on whether there are potentially unforseen circumstances in doing it this way.

The base domain is example.org. I also have admin.example.org, dashboard.example.org and api.example.org. I want each of those subdomains to map to its namesake module (subdomain admin maps to module admin, etc). I configure the Apache virtualhost with the subdomains as serveraliases.

Then I also define the following:

```
SetEnvIf Host ^admin* MODULE_TO_USE=admin
```

Then, in index.php, I have the following:

```
/** Zend_Config_Ini */
require_once 'Zend/Config/Ini.php';

$config = new Zend_Config_Ini(APPLICATION_PATH . '/configs/application.ini', APPLICATION_ENV);
$config = $config->toArray();

$module = $config['resources']['frontController']['defaultModule'];
if(getenv('MODULE_TO_USE')) {
    $module = getenv('MODULE_TO_USE');
    $config['resources']['frontController']['defaultModule'] = $module;
}
$module = ucfirst($module);
$config['bootstrap']['path'] = APPLICATION_PATH . "/{$module}_Bootstrap.php";

/** Zend_Application */
require_once 'Zend/Application.php';

// Create application, bootstrap, and run
$application = new Zend_Application(
    APPLICATION_ENV,
    $config
);
$application->bootstrap()
            ->run();
```

Then, instead of the usual Bootstrap.php file, I have Default_Bootstrap.php, Admin_Bootstrap.php, etc etc... As far as I can figure, because in this case the modules are mapped directly to the subdomains, then using logic to check for those named subdomains in the virtualhost conf (or .htaccess, for that matter) shouldn't break anything. But I'm not a ZF guru, so I can't be sure.

I would appreciate any feedback.

(Note: I know they aren't "real" subdomains, just server aliases, but I've called them subdomains to assist with future searches, as most people will search for "subdomains" as opposed to "serveralises")

Comment: ...Or, another way of looking at this, is that whichever module you are "in", is the default module...

Answer (score 0):

ZF way is to use hostname routing:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/zend.controller.router.html#zend.controller.router.routes.hostname

Comment: Yeah, I looked at that, too. But it doesn't provide a non-polluted bootstrapping method. If I have 10 module bootstraps, they'll all be bootstrapped. In our situation, we require module isolation. And my question wasn't what the ZF approved method is, it was if there are any drawbacks with the method I've outlined above that will jump up and bite us on the ass in the future.

Comment: I had the same problem with bootstrapping too many modules, the best way to avoid it is to add the individual modules using addControllerDirectory on the front controller rather than using addModuleDirectory. I can only say I would prefer this way, you would avoid having many bootstraps and repeating code, but if it works for you then it's fine.